# Optim inside function: promise already under evaluation

Tags: r, function, optimization

The are a few topics about the error message "promise already under evaluation" and scoping. However it doesn't seem to be the case here. I trying to use `optim` inside other function. To reproduce the same error I put a minimal example bellow. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
set.seed(123)

df_ss = data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100), 
                   var2 = rnorm(100), 
                   var3 = rnorm(100), 
                   var4 = rnorm(100))

test <- function(df_ss = df_ss, degree = 3, raw = TRUE, ...){
  # objective function
  objective <- function(beta, df_ss = df_ss) {
    op2 <- lm(formula = I(var1 - beta*var2) ~ poly(I(var3 - beta*var2), degree = degree), data = df_ss)
    return (sum(residuals(op2)^2))
  }

  ss_reg <- optim(1, fn = objective , method ="Brent",lower =-1, upper =1)
}


test()
Error in model.frame.default(formula = I(var1 - beta * var2) ~ poly(I(var3 -  : promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works. Avoid doing `df_ss = df_ss`.

```
test <- function(dat = df_ss, degree = 3, raw = TRUE, ...){
  # objective function
  objective <- function(beta) {
    op2 <- lm(formula = I(var1 - beta*var2) ~ poly(I(var3 - beta*var2), degree = degree, raw = raw), data = dat)
    return (sum(residuals(op2)^2))
  }

  ss_reg <- optim(1, fn = objective , method ="Brent",lower =-1, upper =1)
}

result <- test()
result
# par
# [1] -0.03866607
#
# value
# [1] 80.22191
```